# MongoDB Master and Slave at same time

Tags: mongodb

I have a server that I want to use for testing new app verson (say *staging server*), but at same time I want to use it as replication slave for MongoDB. So, there is two roles:

- always replicate an database to this server (only one database, *original*, with real data)
- after deployment, make a copy of original db, to a new one (`*-staging` db), and test my deployment against this database

I see from docs how to replicate only specified database from one server to another, seems that it's working fine. But the problem that when i've tried to make a copy of existing database, on slave server, it fails with error `not master`. I don't want to make this database copy on master server, because it means that all staging tests will be executed against master server, that doesn't work for me.

Does it mean that I can't have MongoDB master for one database, and slave for another?

Answer (score 2):

Slaves by default are read only but you can achieve what you are trying to do by making it master and slave at the same time by passing both --master and --slave when starting your server:

```
mongod --slave --source master:1234 --master
```